# Is there any way of create an entity in google cloud datastore with custom id ( not auto generated ) via google cloud console?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

my need is to create an entity in a kind via google cloud console.

My issue is that if I choose to create with a numeric ID, it's auto generated. But I wish I could create an entity with my own id numeric. Is there possible using google cloud console ?

My kind is TipoDocumento as shows in image attached to this question.[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible in the Cloud Console.

Note that, in general, if you want to manually assign numeric IDs, you need to allocate them first. This prevents Datastore from later reusing the ID. See the [note at the bottom of this section](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#assigning_identifiers) for more details (or the App Engine [Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Kinds_and_identifiers)/[Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Python_Kinds_and_identifiers) sections).